# How could I customize StaxEventItemWriter to have a control over xml file writing ?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch, stax

I need to generate a xml in spring batch from database records. Spring batch have provided StaxEventItemWriter for generating xml. But My output xml is not usual xml. It has header and body and inside body it has one element which gets repeated in spring batch processing in chunks. The output xml format is as below.I couldn't find a way to override methods provided in StaxEventItemWriter to achieve this.

```
       <Document>
          <header>
           <groupheader>
            ......
           </groupheader>
           <Body>
            <data>
            .......
            </data>
            <record>
            .........
            </record>
            <record>
            .........
            </record>
            <record>
            .........
            </record>
            .........repeating element
          </Body>
    </Document>
```

Comment: did you find a way to get what you were looking for? I have a similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the format of the XML outputted by Spring Batch's `StaxEventItemWriter` is really a function of the marshaller configuration.  It looks like you're trying to generate an XML document with a header.  That is supported via the header callback available in the `StaxEventItemWriter`.  That callback will be executed once when the file is opened.  After that, each item is serialized via the marshaller.  You can read more about the header callback in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxEventItemWriter.html#setHeaderCallback-org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxWriterCallback-